# Base64 encoder in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, base64

can you help me with refactoring this method from java to kotlin, please ? I have a problem with ByteBuffer in return statement. Looks like in Kotlin it doesnt work that way.

```
public String encryptData(Object payload, Key secretKey)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, JsonProcessingException, BadPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
        var initialVector = new byte[INITIAL_VECTOR_SIZE];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(initialVector);
        var cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(initialVector));
        var data = cipher.doFinal(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload).getBytes());
        var byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(initialVector.length + data.length);
        return new String(
                Base64.getEncoder()
                        .encode(byteBuffer
                                        .put(0, initialVector)
                                        .put(INITIAL_VECTOR_SIZE, data))
                        .array());
    }
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: return new String(
                Base64.getEncoder()
                        .encode(byteBuffer
                                        .put(0, initialVector)
                                        .put(INITIAL_VECTOR_SIZE, data))
                        .array());  <--- dont know how to refactor this part to Kotlin

Comment: kotlin does not have `new` keyword, just remove it.

Comment: I know it doesnt have. This whole part is actually wrong in Kotlin that's why I'm asking.

Comment: you need to be specific when you say *wrong*. are you getting error compile time error?

Comment: `put(int, byte[])` method in [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) was added in Java13. Are you sure you are using relevant JDK with Kotlin?

Also it could be rewritten to use older API: `return String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteBuffer.put(initialVector).put(data, INITIAL_VECTOR_SIZE, data.size)).array())`

Answer (score 2):

It's cleaner to setup your `byteBuffer` outside of base 64 conversion. Once you have done that, you can:

```
...
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteBuffer)
```